# Issue with scrolling in JS

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var page1 = document.querySelector("#aaa");
var chiffre;
page1.addEventListener("scroll", deplacer);
function deplacer() {
    alert("a");
    chiffre += 1;
    page1.style.top = chiffre + px;
}
</script>
```

Why it doesn't alert anything when I scroll my `<div id="aaa"></div>` ? Thanks in advance

Comment: You should make a jsFiddle

Comment: a [mcve] would be great!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5u4roob7/1/

Comment: the scroll event on the div isn't happening because... the div isn't scrolling. imagine that.

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs just fine, but you did need to surround `px` in `page1.style.top = chiffre + px;` with quotes `'px'`.

Attaching it to document.body doesn't work, as it's the window that is scrolling, not the body.

```js
var el = window;
var chiffre;

function deplacer() {
    chiffre += 1;
    //el.style.top = chiffre + 'px'; We can't set .style.top on window, so this'll need to be changed.
    alert("a");
};

el.addEventListener("scroll", deplacer);
```

```css
p {
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    color: blue;
    font-size: 100px;
}

p:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>a</p>
<p>a</p>
<p>a</p>
```

Comment: @MathieuGoogle Do you, by any chance, use Chrome 49?

Comment: Look my jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/5u4roob7/6/) and nothings alerts, I am using safari 9...

Comment: I've edited my example to include a working example for `window`, because it's not `document.body` that's scrolling, it's the window.

Answer (score -1):

You don't initialise `chiffre` to anything, do

```
vaf chiffre = 0;
```

Comment: @webdeb That doesn't mean this is a bad answer